# Modificar Controlador para actualizar no insertar

Tags: laravel

Tengo este controlador para Subir en dos tablas a la vez desde un formulario funciona bien pero tengo la duda de como lo puedo modificar  para que en vez de insertar en la tabla Point la actualice alguien me echa una mano?? gracias..

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{

  $dsa = Dsa::Create($request->all());
  $in = new Point;
  $in->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
  $in->uni = $request->get('uni');
  $in->save();

    return redirect()->route('dsa.edit', $dsa->id)->with('info', 'Categoría creada con éxito');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para actualizar un registro en vez de crear uno nuevo debes de utilizar un método diferente, si seguimos API REST debe ser de tipo `PUT`. Sigue estos pasos:

#### 1. Crear ruta

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::post('/ruta/para/crear/registro', 'AlgunControlador@store');
// nuevo:
Route::put('/ruta/para/crear/registro/{id}', 'AlgunControlador@update');
```

Como puedes ver, hemos añadido una nueva ruta del tipo `PUT` y estamos añadiendo una [variable de ruta](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters) la cual traerá el `id` del objeto a actualizar. Esta ruta la estamos mapeando para el método `update` del controlador `AlgunControlador`.

#### 2. Implementar el nuevo método en el controlador

**app/Http/Controllers/AlgunControlador.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // your code
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // buscamos el objecto
    $object = Modelo::findOrFail($id);
    // actualizamos los datos
    $object->udpate($request->only(['field_1', 'field_2', 'etc']));

    return redirect()->route('nombre_de_ruta')->with('info', 'Categoría actualizada con éxito');
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la explicación y por todo lo documentada que esta pero creo que eso actualizaría las dos tablas y necesito crear  nueva Dsa y actualizar solo la Point seria esto posible ??

Answer (score 1):

Por fin.. lo comparto por si le pudiera servir a alguien por simple que sea..

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

  $dsa = Dsa::Create($request->all());
  $in = Point::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();
  if ($in){

  $in->uni = $request->get('uni');
  $in->save();
  }
  else
  {
    $in = new Point;
    $in->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $in->uni = $request->get('uni');
    $in->save();
  }
```